# How to add an entity in EF5 that has child entities but without updating those children

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF5 and POCO classes, and .Net Framework 4.5 in Visual Studio 2012.  I have Parent and child relationship like this:

```
public class Parent {
  [Key]
  public int Id {set; get}
  public string Name {set; get;}
  public int ChildId {set; get;}
  public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child {
      [Key]
      public int Id {set; get}
      public string Name {set; get;}
}
```

I am using EF5 in a Web Api scenario.  The client wants to create a new Parent by sending in JSON like this:

```
{ 
Id: 0, 
Name:'Spock', 
ChildId: 42
}
```

The javascript client shouldn't have to supply the child objects, just the key.

But, to do this, it means in the Web Api method, I have to read the Child entity and set it to the Parent.Child, like this:

```
    parent.Child= (from child in db.Child where child.Id == parent.ChildId select child).FirstOrDefault();
    db.Parent.Attach(parent);
db.Entry(parent).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
```

If I don't set parent.Child to the instance that corresponds to the key, then EF throws an exception:

```
ExceptionMessage=A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.
```

I have also tried adding the new parent object like this:

```
db.Parent.Add(parent);
```

where parent.Child is null, but then Entity Framework gets angry and says:

```
ExceptionMessage=Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table 'MyDB.dbo.Child'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Is there a way I can have a new Parent row inserted without having to read all of the instances of the children, by having only their keys set?  I want the Parent POCO class to have the children populated when a GET (read) the data, so I want the virtual child properties there, but I don't want the client to be able to update the children.  Can I somehow tell EF to ignore the children during an Add or an Attach.  In my examples there is a single child in a 1:1 relationship, but there can be many and in 1:many relationships, so this could get really ugly, and be a big performance hit.

In summary, I don't want EF creating child rows or updating child rows at all, how can I stop it from updating the child entities in a way that doesn't involve reading and setting them all from the database?

Answer (score 0):

The "principal" entity in this relationship is Child (Child records must exist in the database before parent records can be added". The "dependent" entity is parent which can only be added once the child entity is available in the database. Your names don't really match this ...

The child Entity should probably have a Parents navigation property

```
public ICollection<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
```

and you're going to need a mapping for that navigation back to the parent record

```
HasMany(c => c.Parents).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.ChildId);
```

then so long as the child record already exists in the database you can simply write

```
db.Parents.Add(newParent);
```

Comment: A. It would be morrect correct in this example to say "Product" instead of "Parent", and "Category" instead of "Child", you are correct in inderstanding the Dependent/Principle relationship intended.

Comment: B.If I add navigator back to the Parent, then I will need to deal with the Json self-reference loop issues and then turn off ProxyCreation and then figure out Eager loading or Query Paths.
C. I haven't found a good example, tons of articles trying to address this.  Is there a comprehensive example anyone knows of?
D. Is EF6 any better at handling this scenario?

Comment: Or you use a ViewModel. Typically you create a ViewModel that only passes the properties required back and forth between the view and controller. These may be the same as your Entity, without the navigation properties, but generally they tend to be different, with projected data  and / or calculated fields. In complex entities they are often just the properties you need for the view you're using.